# MVC3 Deploying a Web Application Project Using One-Click Publish

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, webdeploy

I am stuck.  I am trying to deploy an MVC3 web application with DBFirst (if that makes any difference) to a shared hosting server.

I have gone through the configuration steps as per the instructions here: 
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd465337(v=vs.100).aspx

When I try and publish the thing and validate the connection I get this error:

'Could not load file or assembly 'Microsoft.Web.Deployment, Version 9.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicTokenKey=31bf385ud364e35' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.'

The web hosting company says that it is a problem with my Web.Config file.

Any ideas?  This is the first time I have ever done this so please excuse my ignorance.

Comment: Does `Microsoft.Web.Deployment.dll` exist within your `bin` folder?

Comment: There are two 'bin' folders.  One is bin which contains ProjectXMVC3.dll (the project is called ProjectXMVC3) and ProjectXMVC3.pdb.  The _bin_deployableAssemblies folder does not contain Microsoft.Web.Deployment.dll although it doesn't sound like it should.

Comment: Um..how? There should only be one...Is it in both `bin` folders?

Comment: Sorry pressed return by accident there.  Thanks for the help

Comment: Every time I see that error I start by adding a reference to whatever assembly, and then setting 'Copy Local' to true in the properties for that reference.  I don't know that it will work, but that's my first step every time I see this.

Comment: So I've gone to add reference and I'm looking through the .NET Framework options (there seem to be a lot) and I can't see it in there. Do you think I'm missing some form package??

Comment: It appears that the dll in question is intended for the IIS server, not for your app.  Make sure you have the same version of .net for both the server and your app. http://forums.asp.net/t/1685882.aspx/1

Comment: I've seen that post.  I'm sure it's the same.  Properties say it's .Net Framework 4 as does the Web.Config and the references refer to runtime version v4.0.30319 which is the same as what the server is supposed to be running.

Comment: I'd attempt to create a empty project and publish that, just to check the web deploy.  If that works, compare the web.config of both for differences.

Comment: Done.  Same error.  What's weird is that if it was connecting to a server it would take some time but this error comes up instantly.

Comment: I'd suggest a new host. Or reinstall Visual Studio if you really think it's on your side.

Comment: Thanks Michael B.  Might try both.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I installed the Web Deploy 3.5 package on my dev station.

http://www.iis.net/downloads/microsoft/web-deploy

I restarted visual studio 2010, reloaded the project, hit publish, tried the "Validate Connection" button again and I got rid of the missing assembly error.